# EF 6 Code-First TPH Inheritance Results in Migrations with Duplicate Columns (sometimes in triplicate)

Tags: entity-framework, migration, duplicates

I have an MVC5 application using EF 6.1

I am using table-per-hierarchy (TPH) inheritance for several entities and in every case I am incurring the same problem...that the migration generates duplicate column definitions within a single table even though the column is only declared in ONE of the derived classes.

```
          CreateTable(
            "dbo.ContactInfos",
            c => new
                {
                    ContactInfoId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    sContactInfoSubTypeId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Value = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150),
                    IsDefault = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    Deleted = c.Boolean(nullable: false),

                    BuildingId = c.Guid(), <-- Contained in ContactInfoBuilding
                    CompanyId = c.Guid(), <-- Contained in ContactInfoCompany
                    OccupancyId = c.Guid(), <-- Contained in ContactInfoOccupancy
                    PersonId = c.Guid(), <-- Contained in ContactInfoPerson
                    BuildingId1 = c.Guid(), <-- Why is this duplicated??
                    CompanyId1 = c.Guid(), <-- Why is this duplicated??
                    OccupancyId1 = c.Guid(), <-- Why is this duplicated??
                    Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Occupant_OccupantId = c.Guid(), <-- Why is this triplicated??
                })
```

My Base Class:

```
public abstract class ContactInfo
{

    [Column("ContactInfoId")]
    [Key]
    public Guid ContactInfoId { get; set; }


    [Column("sContactInfoSubTypeId")]
    public Guid sContactInfoSubTypeId { get; set; }

    [Column("Value")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLengthExceeded")]
    public string Value{ get; set; }

    [Column("IsDefault")]
    public Boolean IsDefault { get; set; }

    public virtual sContactInfoSubType sContactInfoSubType { get; set; }

}
```

My derived class:

```
public class ContactInfoOccupancy: ContactInfo
    {
        [Column("OccupancyId")]
        public Guid OccupancyId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OccupancyId")]
        public virtual Occupant Occupant { get; set; }
    }
```

My DBContext Mapping Code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ContactInfo>().HasRequired(t => t.sContactInfoSubType).WithMany(t => t.ContactInfos).HasForeignKey(d => d.sContactInfoSubTypeId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<ContactInfo>().Property(t => t.ContactInfoId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);            

modelBuilder.Entity<ContactInfoOccupancy>().HasRequired(t => t.Occupant).WithMany(t => t.ContactInfoOccupancies).HasForeignKey(d => d.OccupancyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Finally, in my Occupant object, I have the ContactInfoOccupancies declared in the constructor and as a navigation property:

```
public partial class Occupant
{
    public Occupant()
    {
        this.ContactInfoOccupancies = new List<ContactInfoOccupancy>();
    }

    ...More stuff here that is unrelated...

    public virtual ICollection<ContactInfoOccupancy> ContactInfoOccupancies { get; set; }
```

So, in summary:  I declared my base class as abstract.  I have the FK (OccupancyId for example) declared in only one derived class, and I have the mapping explicitly stated.  I also have only the base-class declared as a DBSet in the DBContext.  However, EF Code-First Migrations seems to be trying to add the fields twice or even three times (once as it should, a second time with the number one appended and a third time with an underscore between the table-name and the column-name).  Any ideas how to stop this?  Commenting out the erroneous lines from the migration doesn't work because the "snapshot" still thinks they exist and any insert/update attempts then fail because the "phantom columns" are still trying to be populated by calls to Context.SaveChanges

I also blew away my database and started a new migration from scratch, resulting in the above-listed migration...so this isn't an artifact resulting from an existing database having an inheritance schema pushed onto it.

Thanks in advance for any help...it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was that we were using ViewModels with MVC and the Scaffolder made the ViewModels inherit from the abstract, base-class Model of ContactInfo instead of the ContactInfoViewModel.  We heavily modified the basic scaffolder to do this, so this was really our code that had a bug, not Microsoft's.

Since ViewModels are supposed to be ignorant of the database, we didn't have any mapping entries in the DBContext for the ViewModels, but the Migration-generator was seeing the relationships based on naming conventions (fields with the table-name followed by Id) within the ViewModels and artificially creating additional relationships within the DBContext due to the VMs inheriting from the base-class Model which was in the Context.

Changing the VMs to inherit from the ContactInfoViewModel removed these "implicit relationships" and all is good.